# Why my custom params not received in Meta Dashboard (react-native-fbsdk-next)

Tags: react-native, react-native-fbsdk, react-native-fbsdk-next

### Bug Report

Not receive custom params in Meta Dashboard, it just show like this
[image: Meta Dashboard]

### To Reproduce

1. Integrating [react-native-fbsdk-next](https://github.com/thebergamo/react-native-fbsdk-next) to my project
2. Trigger logEvent() inside my componentDidMount React Native
3. When I trigger the custom parameters from the bellow code, everything logged and worked as expected. only custom params not logged

```
type AppEventParam = {
  AddType: string;
  Content: string;
  ContentID: string;
  ContentType: string;
  Currency: string;
  Description: string;
  Level: string;
  NumItems: string;
  MaxRatingValue: string;
  OrderId: string;
  PaymentInfoAvailable: string;
  RegistrationMethod: string;
  SearchString: string;
  Success: string;
  ValueNo: string;
  ValueYes: string;
};
```

### Expected Behavior

three of my custom params should be triggered and shows up on Meta Dashboard

### Code Example

Just testing using this code

```
import { AppEventsLogger } from 'react-native-fbsdk-next';

const params = {
     SECV: 123,
     'Transaction ID': 123,
     'Transaction Type': 'awsd'
};
AppEventsLogger.logEvent(AppEventsLogger.AppEvents.InitiatedCheckout, params);
console.log('INITIATED CHECKOUT TRIGGER!!!');
```

### Environment

react-native info

```
info Fetching system and libraries information...
System:
    OS: macOS 13.4.1
    CPU: (8) x64 Apple M2
    Memory: 22.32 MB / 8.00 GB
    Shell: 5.9 - /bin/zsh
  Binaries:
    Node: 14.13.0 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v14.13.0/bin/node
    Yarn: 1.22.19 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v14.13.0/bin/yarn
    npm: 6.14.8 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v14.13.0/bin/npm
    Watchman: 2023.07.24.00 - /opt/homebrew/bin/watchman
  Managers:
    CocoaPods: 1.12.1 - /Users/akhmadyuza/.rbenv/shims/pod
  SDKs:
    iOS SDK:
      Platforms: DriverKit 22.4, iOS 16.4, macOS 13.3, tvOS 16.4, watchOS 9.4
    Android SDK:
      API Levels: 29, 31, 32
      Build Tools: 29.0.2, 30.0.2
      Android NDK: Not Found
  IDEs:
    Android Studio: Not Found
    Xcode: 14.3.1/14E300c - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
  Languages:
    Java: 11.0.20 - /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/zulu-11.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/javac
    Python: Not Found
  npmPackages:
    @react-native-community/cli: Not Found
    react: 16.13.1 => 16.13.1 
    react-native: 0.63.3 => 0.63.3 
    react-native-macos: Not Found
  npmGlobalPackages:
    *react-native*: Not Found
```

ENV Info

```
"react-native-fbsdk-next": "^6.2.0"
"react-native": "0.63.3"
```

Comment: got solution for above problem??

Comment: @priyanka not yet. but i use alternative solution

Comment: please suggest....